# Codeigniter Getting an error of

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I don't how to solve this error. While using the following controller and views in the **CodeIgniter-3.0.0** Version and i change the baseurl also too http://localhost/code/

**controllers:**
Hello.php

```
  <?php
class Hello extends CI_Controller {
    var $name;
    var $color;
    function Hello()
    {
        $this->name = 'Andi';
        $this->color = 'red';
        parent::CI_Controller();
    }
    function you()
    {
        $data['name'] = $this->name;
        $data['color'] = $this->color;
        $this->load->view('you_view',$data);
    }

}
?>
```

**View:**
you_view.php

```
    Hello You!
<font color="<?=$color ?>"><?=$name?></font>
```

**http://localhost/code/index.php/Hello/you**

Got an error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Controller::CI_Controller() in E:\phpprogram\code\application\controllers\hello.php on line 9
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined method CI_Controller::CI_Controller()

Filename: controllers/hello.php

Line Number: 9

Backtrace:
```

Comment: Which version are you using ?

Comment: CodeIgniter-3.0.0  version

Comment: Could you please suggest me any reference page too look for the solutions if u don't mind... Please because i have google many pages but its not worthy too study or learn that framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extend `CI_Controller` not `Controller` in **controllers/Hello.php**

Comment: Thanks #lamzozo i too changed the Controller to CI_Controller on seeing the Welcome Page but while extending that i get the same error as above mentioned. sorry for changed the question.

Comment: Change this line `parent::CI_Contoller()` to `parent::__construct()`. Parent class don't have a method, called CI_Controller. Also suggest, call your constructor also as `__construct()`, not `Hello()`

Comment: Here you go:
http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/30-awesome-codeigniter-tutorials-for-all-skill-levels--net-16915

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `Controller` with `CI_Controller`.

Bookmark to your browser the [user guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/). It is something you will need to visit quite often. Most things are pretty well explained there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your controller:

```
class Hello extends CI_Controller {
    function hello()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function you()
    {
        $this->load->view('you_view');
    }
}
```